# The tag '?php' is disallowed

Tags: php, amp-html

I am new to AMP and am trying to build a new AMP page. I wanted to include PHP but I am getting this error:-

> The tag '?php' is disallowed.

```
<?php $otherCourse= \App\Course::orderBy("order_seq","ASC")->where('status','=',0);
    $otherCourse=$otherCourse->Where(function ($query) {
        $query->orwhere('show_menu', '=',  '2');
        $query->orwhere('show_menu', '=',  '12');
    })->select(DB::raw("group_concat(id) as tid"),'course_name')->groupBy('course_name')->get();

?>
```

Comment: Does the error tell you which line this applies to?

Comment: `;?>
    @foreach($otherCourse as $k=>$v)
<?php` looks wrong. That foreach should be inside PHP tags.

Comment: @karishmanayak your php code is not executing.

Comment: @Bachcha please give me a solution for this.

Comment: @Karishmanayak is your code giving out put?

Comment: @Bachcha when i am execute my code then this error is come --The tag '?php' is disallowed.

Comment: @Karishmanayak  Question - what is the extension of your file and where are you executing this file?, I suppose you are using on client end thatswhy amp treat <?php as tag, PHP scripts are executed on the server.

Comment: @Bachcha my file is running on https://validator.ampproject.org/ please go through the url and add the code and check . and give me a proper solution if you have.

Comment: @Karishmanayak You are using wrong approach, from the beginning i am telling you that your code is not executing. check the link for understand : https://ibb.co/8PyTtmR

Answer (score 0):

The `<?php` tag opens a new block of PHP code. Before you can open another php block, you have to close the previous script with the php close tag: `?>`.

Since you didnt do that, and have multiple occurances of `<?php` it generates an error.

Comment: I already closed the php tag.please check carefully. and the php tag not supported in AMP.Give me a proper answer.

Comment: The closing PHP tag was not in your sample code before you edited. And rudeness will get you nowhere...

Answer (score -1):

At the end of the line you have `get();?>` this `?>` seems accidental or is  out of place. It‘s advised to always put your closing tag on a new line so you see them better when you have multiple php parts mixed with other parts of code that use a different language or are hard typed output.

```php
<?php
  // do something parsed by php
?>
  do something without php
<?php
  // do something parsed by php
?>
  do something without php
```

Comment: You're using short open tags, which have to be enabled by a php setting, and are NOT recommended

Comment: yeah ok. fixed it